# Asymptotic Equipartition Property and $1-\epsilon$ lower bound

Tags: information-theory, typical-sequences

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_set) and [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaarti/Class/10704/lec6_srccoding.pdf) and [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/files/lecture_notes.pdf), the lower bound on the probability that an element is $\epsilon$-typical is $1-\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, and this is derived by using the asymptotic equipartition property which states that the limit of this probability as $n$ goes to infinity is $1$. But why $1-\epsilon$? Can't we pick any number less than n as a lower bound? Why not $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which is higher?

Am I misunderstanding how the AEP is applied? Or is there a practical reason why this lower bound is chosen instead of a better one?

For clarification, the standard result given in all the resources linked above is:

For sufficiently large $n$:

$$\Pr(x^{n}\in A_\epsilon^{(n)})\geq 1-\epsilon$$

But for sufficiently large $n$, every lower bound is true. Why choose the $\epsilon$ in $1-\epsilon$ to be the same as the $\epsilon$ in $A_\epsilon^{(n)}$? I am yet to see a compelling reason for choosing this than a better bound.

Thanks so much.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your question. It is good practice to put in the exact equations into your question so this does not happen. please do that

Comment: @kodlu I have added some clarification of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical statements such as this $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary and can be chosen to be any positive value, however small. That's the whole point.

You saying choose $\epsilon/2$ is just redefining the name of the variable since if $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small and positive so is $\epsilon/2.$

**Edit:** Incorporating the well written comment by @curlycharcoal in this answer may help the OP:

$\epsilon$ is arbitrary, but fixed. We pick an $\epsilon$ and for that fixed $\epsilon$, we can find a large enough $n$, call it $N(\epsilon)$, such that $\forall n\geq N(\epsilon)$ the $1−\epsilon$ bound holds. You're right, we can still work this for a $1−\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ bound, but that would correspond to $\epsilon/2-$typicality and hence a larger than $N(\epsilon)$ minimum for $n$, say $N(\epsilon/2)>N(\epsilon)$.

Practically, you want only a good enough $\epsilon$ instead of as small as possible because that bump in reliability comes at a cost of $N(\epsilon/2)-N(\epsilon)$ delay in your transmission, which may not be worth it. T

Also, increased blocklength $N(\epsilon)$ also results in a larger complexity decoding algorithm. This complexity is sometimes growing exponentially in $N(\epsilon)$ for probabilistic search based decoding algorithms.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not arbitrary in this context, though, right? $\epsilon$ is *also* the constraint on how typical an element needs to be in the set. The reason for this is the question I am asking.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, but fixed. We pick an $\epsilon$ and for that fixed $\epsilon$, we can find a large enough $n$, call it $n'$, such that $\forall n \geq n'$ the $1-\epsilon$ bound holds. You're right, we can still work this for a $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ bound, but that would correspond to $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$-typicality and hence a larger than $n'$ minimum for $n$, say $n'_2$. Practically, you want only a good enough $\epsilon$ instead of as small as possible because that bump in reliability comes at a cost of $n'-n'_2$ delay in your transmission, which may not be worth it.